# I want to add all the checked boxes into the listview in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, checkbox

I am not using **CheckedListBox**, I am using seperate check boxes.

eg- I want to add sandwiches, burger, pasta into the ListView next to the menu
[image: eg- i want to add sandwiches,burger,pasta into the listview next to the menu]

Comment: Keep a list of checkboxes, and go through them using Linq

Comment: If you create a class which contains an item name and price, then you can have a List(Of ThatClass). From that list, you can programmatically create the checkboxes and the prices in Labels (so you can right-align the numbers for neatness) next to them in a Panel (or similar). To get the checked items, you can use `yourPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Checkbox).Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked)` for a For Each loop.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you
rtbResoconto Is RichTextBox:

```
 Private Sub btnGenerareRicevuta_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGeneraRicevuta.Click
    rtbResoconto.AppendText("Calcolatore del Sistema di Gestione del Prestito" + vbNewLine)
    rtbResoconto.AppendText("------------------------------------------------------------------------" + vbNewLine)
    rtbResoconto.AppendText("Inserisci Ammontare Del Prestito" + vbTab + txtImportoPrestito.Text + vbNewLine)
    rtbResoconto.AppendText("Inserisci Numero degli Anni" + vbTab + txtAnniPrestito.Text + vbNewLine)
    rtbResoconto.AppendText("Inserisci gli Interessi Rate" + vbTab + vbTab + txtInteressiRate.Text + vbNewLine)
    rtbResoconto.AppendText("Pagamento Mensile" + vbTab + vbTab + lblPagamentoMensile.Text + vbNewLine)
    rtbResoconto.AppendText("Pagamento Totale" + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + lblTotalePagamento.Text + vbNewLine)
    rtbResoconto.AppendText("-------------------------------------------------------------------------" + vbNewLine)
    rtbResoconto.AppendText("----------------------------Grazie---------------------------------------" + vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).